# launching the image_view node of kinect camera

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

For Kinect, to view depth images on the topic /camera/depth/image, we use this command

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image
```

Now my question is how do I include image_view node in launch file of my package?. Including a node in a launch file is straightforward but I do not know to include `image:=/camera/depth/image` in my launch file. Dose anyone know how?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200460/launching-the-image_view-node-of-kinect-camera/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remapping is done with the [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) tag. Running image_view from within a launch file would look something like this:

```
<node name="image_view" type="image_view" pkg="image_view">
  <remap from="image" to="/camera/depth/image"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2015-01-06**:
Thanks. But there is still a problem. Not any window pops up to show the output of camera and there is no errors!! so what is the problem?